# Does stable release of MAAS on Ubuntu 18.04.1 support Cavium ThunderX2 (ARM-based) server?

Tags: 18.04, maas, arm, ipmi

On my setup, MAAS server can power on/off the appliance. Commissioning failed. Machine summary shows CPU/Memory/Storage unknown.

Looked inside a wireshark trace, communication between MAAS server and appliance over IMPI is active; however sessions with data (RMCP+) are encrypted.

I am not sure if MAAS server internal database needs to be updated for recognition of the Cavium ThunderX2 Saber machine type.